# Gradle-Writing env variable's value to manifest file

Tags: gradle, groovy, environment-variables, build-process

I am trying to read env variable "BUILD_NUMBER" from system variable and write to MANIFEST.MF .

Below is the gradle script .

```
war {
     doFirst {

        manifest {
            attributes("build-version": "$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER")
        }
    }
        archiveName 'APP007.war'
    }
```

The above script is creating attribute

> "build-version"

but the value that is being written to the file is

> "null"

.

I have created the env variable **"BUILD_NUMBER"** and the value that I have given is **"APP007.2016.02"**.

Any idea why it is null ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER')`

Comment: How bout `attributes("build-version": System.env.BUILD_NUMBER)` without String interpolation?

Comment: I had to restart my system , after that it was able to read build number correctly.I am sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above script started working after I restarted my system .Not deleting this since it may help others .